# Compact string data type in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How can I compact the `dtype` (which is effectively about memory usage) in a numpy string array, where the maximum string length, say `U5`,  is shorter than that is defined in the `dtype` attribute, say `U10`.

One way to "compact" the `dtype` is to explicitly cast it to `U5`, but can this be done automatically by some function calls without mannually inspecting the string length?

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['a', 'bb', 'cc'], ['aaabc', 'ccc', 'b']], dtype='U10')

# Non-existing pseudo function
>>> a = compact(a)
>>> print(a.dtype)
dtype('<U5')
```

so the function `compact` compacts the redundant `U10` to `U5`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it for both `unicode`/`str` ('U') and `bytes` ('S') arrays:

```
def compact(str_arr): 
    dtype = (str_arr.dtype.kind, np.char.str_len(str_arr).max()) 
    return np.asarray(str_arr, dtype)
```